# How can I change foreground for specific cell from DataGrid c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

To the find specific cell from the DataGrid I use code from [HERE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/290d3c67-440e-4037-86b6-cf668990b5da/how-to-loop-through-all-the-the-cells-in-datagrid?forum=wpf) and it works. But this code only solves half of my problem.

First I want to find some specific cells and then change the foreground to a specific color.

Here is my method to do this. But the foreground is not changed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGrd.Items.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGrd.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = GetCell(i, j);
        TextBlock tb = cell.Content as TextBlock;

        if (j == 1)
        {
            double measure = double.Parse(tb.Text);

            if (measure > 22.5)
            {
                cell.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

I start with debugger the line `cell.Foreground = Brushes.Red;` is running but when I see the result no cell has red foreground.

Xaml:

```
<DataGrid BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Name="grdFilter" Width="900" MinHeight="430" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ColumnWidth="*" ItemsSource="{Binding Datas}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="13" FontStyle="Italic" Binding="{Binding Path=Date}" Header="{catel:LanguageBinding ResourceName=DateTimesSplashScreen}" />  

                    <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="13" FontStyle="Italic" Binding="{Binding Path=AirTemperatureValue}" Header="{catel:LanguageBinding ResourceName=SensorOneColorSettings}" />

                    <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="13" FontStyle="Italic" Binding="{Binding Path=HumidityValue}" Header="{catel:LanguageBinding ResourceName=SensorTwoColorSettings}" />

                    <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="13" FontStyle="Italic" Binding="{Binding Path=FluidTemperatureValue}" Header="{catel:LanguageBinding ResourceName=SensorThreeColorSettings}">
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="13" FontStyle="Italic" Binding="{Binding Path=LightValue}" Header="{catel:LanguageBinding ResourceName=SensorFourColorSettings}" />


                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

**EDIT:** Now when I try to fixed I find is changed the foreground but is not save after method is finish. **How can I save the changes of the foreground**?

Comment: hows ur xaml code, I mean hows its binded.. cell.Foreground and tb.Foreground = Brushes.Red should do the trick if its binded properly.

Comment: except everything else `for (int j = 0; j < dataGrd.Columns.Count; j++)` loop is redundant. `DataGridCell cell = GetCell(i, 1);` would be enough

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the `Cell` foreground colour rather than the `TextBlock` foreground colour

Replace

```
cell.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
```

with

```
tb.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
```

Comment: Again is not changed